# how do i get label's text on the next view's navigationbar?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i have a customcell in which i have a label.now i want the text on the selected cell's label in the nextview's navigation bar? how do i get it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//in the main controller didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithTitle:label.text];

//in the 2nd controller:

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)theTitle {
    if(![super init]) return nil;
    self.title = theTitle;
}
```